# Do ajax if user types inside an input with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a `jQuery.ajax()` inside a function named `helloworld()`. Whenever the user types inside a search input:

```
<input type="search" id="search">
```

I want to run that function whenever the user has typed at least 3 letters inside it. And I only want to run it after 1 second from the point that they released the key. So delay of 1 second, otherwise, it will run continuously while they are typing.

What's the appropriate approach to this?

EDIT: Judging by the comments, I am looking to "debounce" the function.

Comment: I'm at beginner level of javascript, if you can't tell. :)

Comment: I simply want to run the ajax function according to the conditions I noted above.

Comment: Search for questions about "debouncing".

Comment: I will bounty this question with 50 points when eligible.